# ¿Cómo podría aplicar correctamente la sintaxis?

Tags: python, python-3.9

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import re # modulo de expresiones regulares

def validarNombre(nombreUsuario):
     if len(nombreUsuario) >= 6 and len(nombreUsuario) <= 12 and re.search('[a-z]', nombreUsuario) and re.search('[0-9]', nombreUsuario):
        return 'Nombre de usuario válido'

    nombreUsuario = input('Ingrese un nombre de Usuario: ')
    print(validarNombre(nombreUsuario))
```

¿Cómo puedo usar la misma sintaxis de `re.search` para decir que también se cumpla la condición de que sí, el nombre de usuario ingresado **NO tiene caracteres especiales** retorne el mensaje de **'Nombre de usuario válido'**.

*De antemano muchas gracias a la persona que me pueda ayudar*

Comment: Niega la sentencia con `not` además puedes simplificar esa búsqueda creando una expresión regular

Comment: el `not` debe ir antes del `re.search`?

Comment: Pues sip, solo niegas la expresión

Comment: Entiendo, lo probé y funciona perfectamente. Gracias por tu ayuda Christian, siempre respondes a todas mis dudas. Revisaré igualmente eso de que me ahorraría esto creando una expresión regular. Soy nuevo en python, entonces no comprendo muchas cosas.

Comment: de nada ^_^, puedes usar `regex = re.compile(r"[a-z0-9].",re.I)`, luego lo utilizas asi `regex.search("cadena")`, el método `compile()` permite crear una expresión regular, igual puedes aprender más leyendo la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular "`[a-z0-9]{6,12}$`" reconoce las palabras formadas por letras minúsculas y digitos, que tengan entre 6 y 12 caracteres, y que no estén seguidas de nada.

La función para validar el nombre es:

```
import re # modulo de expresiones regulares

patron = re.compile(r"[a-z0-9]{6,12}$")

def validarNombre(nombreUsuario):
    if patron.match(nombreUsuario):
        return 'Nombre de usuario válido'
    else:
        return 'Nombre de usuario no válido'
```

Usamos `re.match` pues esto obliga a que el patrón calce desde la primera posición del nombre.

#### Demo

```
import re # modulo de expresiones regulares

patron = re.compile(r"[a-z0-9]{6,12}$")

def validarNombre(nombreUsuario):
    if patron.match(nombreUsuario):
        return 'Nombre de usuario válido'
    else:
        return 'Nombre de usuario no válido'
        
tests = [
    "user",
    "user1023",
    "raz:on",
    "_ADMIN_",
    "Antonio"
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, validarNombre(test))
```

produce:

```
user Nombre de usuario no válido
user1023 Nombre de usuario válido
raz:on Nombre de usuario no válido
_ADMIN_ Nombre de usuario no válido
Antonio Nombre de usuario no válido

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código debería servir también:

```
import re


def validarNombre(nombre):
    if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12}$', nombre):
        return "Nombre de usuario válido"
    else:
        return "Nombre de usuario NO válido"


nombreUsuario = input('Ingrese un nombre de usuario: ')
print(validarNombre(nombre=nombreUsuario))
```

La expresión regular `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12}$` coincide con cualquier cadena compuesta por entre 6 y 12 characteres (en minúscula o mayúscula, si solo se permiten characteres en mínúscula hay que quitar el `A-Z`) o números.